# Fork a plugin to target multiple version of an application?

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, git-fork

Let's say I have an application, **MySuperApp**, that exists in two versions:

- V 1, that runs with .Net 3.5 SP1 and that is incompatible with .Net > 4
- V 2, that runs with .Net 4.5

The application has a plugin system, and I wrote a plugin for the V 1.

Now I want to target the V2. But I still want to maintain the version for the V 1.

Is there any clean way to structure my source code, in order to share a common code base? I also want to benefits of the new features of the V2 when applicable. When fixing a bug in the V1, the V2 should benefits of the fix too.

I'm wondering if using GIT (which is our source control service) can help me to reach my goal. If I "fork" the original project, will I reach my goal?

Answer (score 1):

Git could help you if you want a branch per version.

For example if you don't plan to add new features to V1 but only bugfixes, you could create branches `V1` and `master`, work on a day-to-day basis on `master` (ie: on your plugin v2), and occasionally add bugfix on `V1` (and then merge them back on `master`).

The advantage is that you won't have to handle both versions in a same code base.
The drawback is that it won't be convenient if you want to be able to work on both at the same time.

You can find an example of this approach here: https://github.com/gturri/hidden/network :

- This project uses the branch `master` as the main branch for its "V2"
- It also has an old `v_nonJQuery` branch which isn't meant to get new features

On the other hand, if you want both version in your code base, I don't think Git can provide any particular help (besides versionning your code)